# Tkinter Python, como puedo borrar/ocultar label/entry/frames al presionar un boton?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy aprendiendo Tkinter de nuevo, y tengo este programa que se conecta a una base de datos SQLite, la aplicación funciona correctamente, solo tengo una duda sobre Tkinter, al momento de cambiar de opcion, se quedan las etiquetas y cajas de texto de la opción anterior, por lo cual da mal aspecto al diseño del programa, mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de borrar u ocultar estas labels, al momento de seleccionar otra opción?. ¿Quizás debería de hacerlo de otra forma?. El codigo como repito funciona bien, simplemente es por la parte del diseño de tkinter, que tengo esa duda, espero alguien me pueda decir si conoce alguna manera de hacer que esto no suceda, o que cuando se presione un boton se borren los labels de la otra funcion, para que no se vea combinado. Muchas gracias.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import sqlite3
import datetime
from sqlite3 import Error
import os
from tkinter import scrolledtext
#SE CREA LA BASE DE DATOS

#IMPLEMENTAR UN SCRIPT EN PYTHON3 QUE CREE UNA TABLA DE REGISTRO DE LLAMADAS Y DEBERÁ TENER LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS
#FOLIO NUMERICO PK, NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA QUE LLAMÓ, FECHA DE LA LLAMADA.

#IMPLEMENTAR OTRO SCRIPT QUE PERMITA REGISTRAR LAS LLAMADAS REALIZADAS (CAPTURANDO INCLUSO LA FECHA)
#Y REALIZAR BUSQUEDA DE LLAMADAS SEGUN LA FECHA EN QUE FUERON REALIZADAS.
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")
ventana.title("Registrador de llamadas")
#ventana.iconbitmap('C:/Users/hugo_/Desktop/GUI/favicon.ico')

ventana.configure(bg="gray65")









def crear_db():
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect("LlamadasDB.db") as conn:
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS llamadas(Folio_numerico INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nombre TEXT NOT NULL, Fecha_llamada TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);")
            print("Tabla creada exitosamente")
    except Error as e:
        print (e)
    except:
        print(f"Se produjo el siguiente error: {sys.exc_info()[0]}")

#Se crea la base de datos SQLite, en caso de que no exista
if os.path.isfile('LlamadasDB.db'):
    pass
else:
    crear_db()













def despliegue_registro():
    global Label_nombre
    Label_nombre = tkinter.Label(ventana, text = "Ingresa tu nombre:", bg= "Gray85").grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    global Nombre_C
    Nombre_C=tkinter.StringVar()
    global entry_nombre
    entry_nombre=ttk.Entry(textvariable=Nombre_C)
    entry_nombre.grid(column=3, row=0)

    global Label_fecha
    Label_fecha = tkinter.Label(ventana, text = " la fecha (dd/mm/yyyy) :", bg= "Gray85").grid(column=2, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    global Fecha_C
    Fecha_C=tkinter.StringVar()
    global entry_fecha
    entry_fecha=ttk.Entry(textvariable=Fecha_C)
    entry_fecha.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    boton4 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text= "Aceptar", command=insertar_llamada)
    boton4.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)












def insertar_llamada():
    
    while True:
        Nombre = str(Nombre_C.get())
        Fecha = str(Fecha_C.get())

        fecha_convertida = datetime.datetime.strptime(Fecha, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
        try:
            with sqlite3.connect("LlamadasDB.db") as conn:
                print("Conexión establecida")
                mi_cursor = conn.cursor()
                fecha_con_tiempo = datetime.datetime.combine(fecha_convertida, datetime.datetime.min.time()) #Es importante complementar la fecha con la parte horaria
                valores = {"Nombre":Nombre, "Fecha_llamada": fecha_con_tiempo}
                mi_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO llamadas (Nombre,Fecha_llamada)VALUES(:Nombre, :Fecha_llamada)", valores)
                print("Registro agregado exitosamente")

                messagebox.showinfo("Informacion", "¡Llamada registrada exitosamente!")
                Nombre_C.set("")
                Fecha_C.set("")
        except Error as e:
            print (e)
        except:
            print(f"Se produjo el siguiente error: {sys.exc_info()[0]}")
        finally:
            if (conn):
                conn.close()
                print("Se ha cerrado la conexión")
        break
    



def consulta_boton():
    label3=ttk.Label(ventana, text="Ingresa la fecha de la llamada\n a consultar, (dd/mm/yyyy)")
    label3.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    #label4=ttk.Label(ventana, text="Fecha:")
    #label4.grid(column=2, row=1)

    global fecha_capturada
    fecha_capturada=tkinter.StringVar()
    entry_fecha=ttk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=fecha_capturada)
    entry_fecha.grid(column=2, row=1)

    boton_consulta=ttk.Button(ventana, text="Consultar", command=select_sqlite)
    boton_consulta.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

    global scrolledtext1
    scrolledtext1=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(ventana, width=40, height=10)
    scrolledtext1.grid(column=2, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)
def select_sqlite():
    fecha_cap = str(fecha_capturada.get())
    fecha_consultar = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_cap, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect("LlamadasDB.db", detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES) as conn:
            mi_cursor = conn.cursor()
            criterios = {"fecha":fecha_consultar}
            mi_cursor.execute("SELECT Folio_numerico, Nombre, Fecha_llamada FROM llamadas WHERE DATE(Fecha_llamada) = :fecha;", criterios)
            registros = mi_cursor.fetchall()

            
            respuesta=registros
            if registros:
                scrolledtext1.delete(1.0, tkinter.END)
                messagebox.showinfo("Informacion", "Datos encontrados con éxito")
                for fila in respuesta:
                    scrolledtext1.insert(tkinter.END, "Folio:"+str(fila[0])+
                                                    "\nNombre:"+fila[1]+
                                                    "\nFecha llamada:"+str(fila[2])+"\n\n")
            else:
                scrolledtext1.delete(1.0, tkinter.END)
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Llamada no encontrada.", icon='error')                
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print (e)
    except Exception:
        print(f"Se produjo el siguiente error: {sys.exc_info()[0]}")
    finally:
        if (conn):
            conn.close()
            print("Se ha cerrado la conexión con la base de datos")
        

    


def salir():
    exit()







boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text= "Registrar Llamada",  height = 2, command=despliegue_registro,background="azure")
boton1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)

boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text= "Consulta Llamada", height = 2, command=consulta_boton,background="azure")
boton2.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=0, pady=60)

boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text= "Salir", width=14, height = 2, command=salir, background="azure")
boton3.grid(column=0, row=20, padx=0, pady=10)









ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remontado su pregunta esto sería lo que haría con un mínimo ejemplo básico sin necesidad de publicar todo el código usando un enfoque orientado a objetos:

```
import tkinter as tk

class WindowExample(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Agregar los widgets....

        self.labelExample = tk.Label(self, text="Este es un ejemplo de un widget (en este caso un label)")
        self.labelExample.place(x=13, y=15)

        HideLabelButton = tk.Button(self, text="Ocultar el label", command=self.HideLabel)
        ShowLabelButton = tk.Button(self, text="Mostrar el label", command=self.ShowLabel)

        HideLabelButton.place(x=485, y=12)
        ShowLabelButton.place(x=359, y=12)

    def ShowLabel(self, event=None): # Mostrar los widgets por medio de esta función al hacer clic
        self.labelExample.place(x=13, y=15)

    def HideLabel(self, event=None): # Ocultar los widgets por medio de esta función al hacer clic
        self.labelExample.place_forget() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = WindowExample()
    root.title('Ejemplo ventana: Ocultar y mostrar widgets')
    root.geometry('600x80')
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```

Ejemplo usando programación procedimental:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Ejemplo ventana: Ocultar y mostrar widgets')
root.geometry('600x80')
root.resizable(0,0)

# Agregar los widgets....

labelExample = tk.Label(root, text="Este es un ejemplo de un widget (en este caso un label)")
labelExample.place(x=13, y=15)

def ShowLabel(event=None): # Mostrar los widgets por medio de esta función al hacer clic
    labelExample.place(x=13, y=15)

def HideLabel(event=None): # Ocultar los widgets por medio de esta función al hacer clic
    labelExample.place_forget() 

HideLabelButton = tk.Button(root, text="Ocultar el label", command=HideLabel)
ShowLabelButton = tk.Button(root, text="Mostrar el label", command=ShowLabel)

HideLabelButton.place(x=485, y=12)
ShowLabelButton.place(x=359, y=12)

root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```

Información general:

- `place_forget` lo utilizo porque hace referencia a el administrador de geometría `place`, no use `place_forget` si está usando otro administrador de geometría como `pack` o `grid`. En esos casos use `pack_forget` o `grid_forget`.
- Cuando desaparezca el widget, se retoma especificando el posicionamiento del widget en la ventana dependiendo del administrador de geometría que utilice usted.
- Otra opción es usar `lift` y `lower`. Esto cambia el orden de apilamiento de los widgets en la ventana. Si quiere hacerlo visible el widget use `lift` y para ocultarlo use `lower`.

Algunas cosas para tener en cuenta en futuras preguntas:

**No use espacios innecesarios en su código**, esto genera un gasto inútil de espacios en el código que está realizando y desvía una estructura coherente en el código.

**Evite publicar todo el código**, esto genera una completa dificultad para poder entender su enfoque en la pregunta o lo que está intentando hacer, lo correcto es que especifique su problema exacto en el código especificando el problema.

Retomando lo anterior, le recomendaría organizar su código ya que está muy confuso y desordenado, por tanto, en estos caso utilice una organización más adecuada o coherente, las funciones están muy separadas unas de las otras lo cual genera un uso innecesario de espacios en el código y evite el uso de comodines o la importación generalizado de un módulo (*) ya que a veces puede resultar difícil retomar una variable o clase en especifico de módulo, utilizar en otros módulos los comodines si lo permite su documentación o lo especifica pero en el caso Tkinter no lo recomendable.

Para más información consulte la [documentación de Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/tk.html).

Comment: Pero... ¿No hay una forma de enviar un comando que limpie todo el lienzo de la ventana?. He visto que había un comando "destroy" que elimina la ventana entera, pero ¿No hay otro que borre el lienzo sin destruir la ventana? Saludos y gracias.